# Why $(window).load() doesn't work in IE10

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have the following script:

```
function AnimateRotate(d){
    var elem = $("#imgLogoWM");
    //elem.fadeIn(2000);
    $(elem).hide();
    $(elem).each(function(i) {
        if (this.complete) {
            $(this).fadeIn(1500);
        } else {
            $(this).load(function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(2000);
            });
        }
    });

    /*$({deg: -60}).animate({deg: d}, {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function(now){
            elem.css({
                 transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
            });
            elem.fadeIn(2000);
        }
    });*/
}

$(window).load(function (){
    timer = setTimeout('auto_reload()', 1800000);
    AnimateRotate(0);
});

var timer = null;
function auto_reload() {
    window.location = 'index.htm';
}
```

It works great in IE < 10 and FF and Chrome and Avant and Opera. The `AnimateRotate(0);` does not work in IE10. Any idea how to go around it so it works in IE10 as well?

Comment: What does you console tell you?

Comment: I am using JQuery 1.11.0. The timer line is working correctly but the AnimateRotate isn't

Comment: What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: The div has an image which is supposed to fade in, but it's not fading in when the page loads.

Comment: What does the load have to do with it if the animate code is what is not working? Does the load get triggered?

Comment: I am calling the animate function once the page loads.

Comment: 1800000 milliseconds = 30 minutes
Why do you want to run "AnimateRotate" after 30 minutes again!?
If you really want to run it once the page is ready, use $(document).ready( ...function stuff ...) 
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Is that what it is doing? I thought window.load() only fires when the page loads and then the timer kicks in? I want to refresh the page every 30 minutes but animaterotate only each time it loads. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Please try out this smaller code
`function AnimateRotate(d){
    var elem = $("#imgLogoWM");
    elem.hide();
    elem.fadeIn(1500);
}

$(function (){
    timer = setTimeout('auto_reload', 1800000);
    AnimateRotate(0);
});`

Comment: added fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3LKkN/1/

Comment: I think that solved the problem. I guess the `$(window).load()` isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up: use document-ready rather than onload: api.jquery.com/ready

```
$(document).ready( ...function stuff ...)  or with less code
$( function(){ ...function stuff ...});
```

---

maybe you like to hand over the variable name "auto_reload"

```
setTimeout(auto_reload, 1800000)
```

to be executed later on instead of the immediately executed function "auto_reload()" to the timeout method. Checkout, if IE does take care of this.

Comment: It was weird, all of a sudden it's fading in :/

Comment: for information about timeout take a look at http://devdocs.io/dom/window.settimeout